# Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping

Tags: struts2

hallo,

i m newbie struts. i have eclipse helios + strust 2 + tomcat7.

i works fine, but it bother me : 
Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping

why ? should i solve it (it is just INFO not WARNING or ERROR). 
[link text](http://www.flickr.com/photos/56834047@N06/5282713120/lightbox/)

thanks in Advance, 
Stev

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a jar for logging.  Please set up an empty struts2 application as per: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/how-to-create-a-struts-2-web-application.html

See the bottom two links starting with "Create Struts 2 Web Application..." the maven one will have you add log4j.